# Cортировка datatable в datagrid по столбцу дата c#

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, datetime, datatable

Создаю таблицу:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("Таблица");
```

header - заголовок столбца "Дата"

Добавляю столбец:

```
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(header, typeof(DateTime)));
```

При записи в данный столбец данных вида 17:42:48 15-06-2016 у меня обрезается время.

Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы время все же отображалось в ячейке при просмотре в `DataGrid` и таблицу можно было бы сортировать по столбцу "Дата" именно по дате а не по текстовому значению.

Подскажите в каком направлении искать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.Columns[header].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy";
```

Это ищешь?

Comment: т.е. мне не надо задавать typeof(DateTime)?

Comment: Тебе надо задавать как именно его отображать. Т.е. настройки по умолчанию не соответствуют твоим потребностям. Так что ты просто задашь свой формат приведения к строке и grid его подменит для этой ячейки.